# Redirection in jQuery with an HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP page with an HTML table. Then I have a button where I can modify my table with a form. After the modification I would like to redirect to a PHP page with some SQL code. But my code didn't really work and I don't find the error.
The navigator says:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '+'. Expected an identifier as property
>   name.

```
$("#linktest").click(function(event) {

$.ajax({
    url: './testsql.php',
    data: {
        'abv=' + abreviation + '&descr=' + description + '&lg=' + largeur + '&ht=' + longueur
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: ajax_success,
    error: function(code, status, error) {
        console.log('code : ' + code + '\n' + 'status : ' + status + '\n' + 'error : ' + error);
    }
});
});

});
```

Comment: Send data like `data: {
            'abv' : abreviation,  'descr' : description, 'lg': largeur,  'ht' :longueur
        }`

Comment: There is no PHP or HTML in the question. Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

The data parameter is expecting an array, not a string.

Try this:

```
$("#linktest").click(function(event) {

$.ajax({
    url: './testsql.php',
    data: {
        abv: abreviation, 
        descr: description, 
        lg: largeur, 
        ht: longueur
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: ajax_success,
    error: function(code, status, error) {
        console.log('code : ' + code + '\n' + 'status : ' + status + '\n' + 'error : ' + error);
    }
});
});

});
```